# Fix duplicate information in R

Tags: r

I'd like to know why I'm getting my output with duplicate values. Notice that I have twice values ​​for `Wednesday`, `Thursday` and `Friday`. How can I fix this?

Executable code below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)


df1<-structure(list(Id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), date1 = c("2021-06-28", 
"2021-06-28", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-28"), 
date2 = c("2021-06-18","2021-06-19", "2021-06-20", "2021-06-25", "2021-06-26", "2021-06-27"), 
Week = c("Wednesday","Thursday", "Friday", "Wednesday","Thursday", "Friday"), 
DT = c(1, NA_character_, NA_character_,1, NA_character_, NA_character_), Category = c("AB","CD", "EF", "AB", "CD", "EF"), 
Time = c(2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"))

f2 <- function(df1,idd,ds,codagr,dt) {
  
  nms <- c('Time|time')
  
  mtime <- df1 %>% mutate(DT = replace_na(DT, "")) %>% 
    filter(Id==idd,Week == ds, Category == codagr,DT == dt) %>% 
    group_by(Id,Week,Category,DT) %>% 
    summarise(across(matches(nms), mean, .names = 'Time',na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'keep') %>% 
    mutate(Time = format(round(Time, digits = 2), nsmall = 2))
  
  return(mtime)
}


df1 %>% mutate(DT = replace_na(DT, "")) %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(f2(df1,Id,Week,Category, DT))%>%
 select(-c(date1, date2))%>%data.frame()

  Id      Week DT Category Time
1  1 Wednesday  1       AB 3.00
2  1  Thursday          CD 3.50
3  1    Friday          EF 3.00
4  1 Wednesday  1       AB 3.00
5  1  Thursday          CD 3.50
6  1    Friday          EF 3.00
```

Comment: Why do you need `f2`?

Comment: So, I know it's possible to do it directly, but I'm working on a problem, which has several functions, and this one will be necessary as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I don't even understand, why your code actually works, since I don't understand what

```r
mutate(f2(df1, Id, Week, Category, DT))
```

does. In my understanding, this is an *usual* way of using `mutate`. I acutally only know `mutate(new_var = do_stuff())` and `mutate(across(...))`.

However: If we take a look at

```r
df1 %>% 
  mutate(DT = replace_na(DT, "")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(f2(df1,Id,Week,Category, DT))
```

we get

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Rowwise: 
     Id date1      date2      Week      DT    Category Time 
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     <chr> <chr>    <chr>
1     1 2021-06-28 2021-06-18 Wednesday "1"   AB       3.00 
2     1 2021-06-28 2021-06-19 Thursday  ""    CD       3.50 
3     1 2021-06-28 2021-06-20 Friday    ""    EF       3.00 
4     1 2021-06-28 2021-06-25 Wednesday "1"   AB       3.00 
5     1 2021-06-28 2021-06-26 Thursday  ""    CD       3.50 
6     1 2021-06-28 2021-06-27 Friday    ""    EF       3.00
```

As we can see, the `Time` column has changed, but the at the moment, there are *no* duplicated data. Compare row 1 to row 4 you see that there is a difference in column `date2`.

The next step `select(-c(date1, date2))` just removes those columns, so *now* there is no difference between row 1 and row 4 (for example) anymore:

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Rowwise: 
     Id Week      DT    Category Time 
  <dbl> <chr>     <chr> <chr>    <chr>
1     1 Wednesday "1"   AB       3.00 
2     1 Thursday  ""    CD       3.50 
3     1 Friday    ""    EF       3.00 
4     1 Wednesday "1"   AB       3.00 
5     1 Thursday  ""    CD       3.50 
6     1 Friday    ""    EF       3.00
```

So for now and the sake of completeness, you current code can be simplified to

```r
df1 %>%
  mutate(DT = replace_na(DT, ""),
         across(c(date1, date2), as.Date)) %>%
  group_by(Id, Week, Category, DT) %>%
  summarise(across(matches("(t|T)ime"), mean, .names = 'Time', na.rm = TRUE),
            .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(Time = format(round(Time, digits = 2), nsmall = 2))
```

Perhaps this gives you a clue for the problem you are working on.

One more thing: If you want/need to apply custom functions on your dataset or parts of your dataset, the `purrr` package with its `map_*`, `imap_*` and/or `map2_*` functions might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty fix, but `distinct_all()` will remove duplicates

Ouput:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Rowwise: 
     Id Week      DT    Category Time 
  <dbl> <chr>     <chr> <chr>    <chr>
1     1 Wednesday "1"   AB       3.00 
2     1 Thursday  ""    CD       3.50 
3     1 Friday    ""    EF       3.00
```

Comment: Thanks @Tom, but I would like to better understand the reason for this duplication. What is wrong in my code to do these duplications?